# Set C++ project

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have C++ project nased on CMake build system in my WSL Ubuntu. I open it Visual Studio Code  by comand `code .`. But how to tell system it is C++ project? There is no folder .vscode created in project root catalog.

Comment: create a launch config, this will create `.vscode`, create a task to call `cmake` and `make`, or use the cmake extension